# Best programming languages to create technical charts for stocks on the server side

Tags: charts

What programming languages are best suited to create technical charts for stocks on the server side and then stream out to http and see it on the browser.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say what is "best".

This is something that Python can do well since it has add-on libraries for complex mathematical data manipulation such as [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and for quantitative finance such as [Quantlib](https://www.quantlib.org/index.shtml). [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is a very flexible Python charting library.

In addition, there is an IronPython-based spreadsheet called [Resolver One](https://web.archive.org/web/20140531064853/http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-one/) that is popular in the financial services industry and they have an add-on that [turns any spreadsheet into a web application](https://web.archive.org/web/20140726013532/http://www.resolversystems.com/products/resolver-server/).

If you did decide to use Resolver, you should be able to use almost any Python or .NET library and integrate it with your application.

I would suggest that you take a look at SVG as the graphical format for the technical charts because you can zoom into these charts in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Any language with a graphical library will do. I know of implementations in Perl, C++, and Java

Answer (score 0):

The perfect language for you would be [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), here's why. You can write your serverside program using Scala, and you can then use the [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) framework to display the output(The Chart) to the browser(Client Side). The output will then be handled using Javascript.

Many websites currently use this method, for example, Twitter and Facebook.